# Structuring Firestore for efficiency and minimum reads

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Context:
Assume I have an application that shows a list of restaurants & 100000 restaurants to show.
Each restaurant belong to a category.eg: Indian.
I want to show the users the individual category they want to view.

approach 1: Add all restaurants to collection and save the document id in a array belonging to the specified category. So if I want all Indian restaurants I would just get the array Indian which will contain all the Indian restaurants Id's and load them.

approach 2:Add all restaurants to collection and give each document a category. So when the user needs list of Indian restaurants I would just use where() to filter them out.
In this approach does firestore bill me for all 100000 document reads and is this approach efficient ?

Is there a better approach for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same.

Firestore does not charge for documents that don't match a query. When you use a filter to match documents in a query, you are only charged reads for the documents returned from the query.

Use either approach and pick the one that works best for you.